# Sql Server: how to LOOKUP in sql server equivalent to LOOKUP in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @Lines int, @Qty int, @Line2 int
SELECT @Line1 = Line
FROM   dbo.PRODUCT
WHERE  ID='100'
AND    SubID = '011'

print @Line1

SELECT @Line2 = Line_num
      ,@Qty = Qty_num
FROM dbo.Equip
WHERE Qty_num= 
CASE WHEN Line_num= @Line1 
       THEN Qty_num
     WHEN Line_num <  @Line1
       THEN Qty_num - 1
END
```

print @Lines2 
print @Qty

In dbo.Equip table:

```
Line_num      Qty_num
20          3
29          4
39          5
```

When the ouput of @Line1 is the same as Line_num in dbo.Equip, 29 for example, then the Qty_num is 4; but if the output of @Line1 is not the same
as Line_num above, 25 for example, then I need to look up the list of 
Line_num (20, 29, 39).  Since Line_num 29 is too big for 25, then I need to
get the Line_num above 29, which is 20 to get its Qty_num 3.

I think in my 2nd Case statement, it doesn't know which Line_num to look when it is 25, so I don't get 3 as the result, but I'm not sure what is the way to look it up and find the right Line_num in order to get Qty_num.  The list of Line_num is quite long in real life so I don't want to 
use case statement to look up each Line_num.  Any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for is a way to get the line where the line number is the highest value that is less than or equal to @Line1.

So, instead of a case statement, you can do:

```
SELECT @Line2 = Line_num
  ,@Qty = Qty_num
FROM dbo.Equip
WHERE Line_num = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Line_num
    FROM dbo.Equip
    WHERE Line_num <= @Line1
    ORDER BY Line_num DESC
)
```